# how to know if device is left landscape or right landscape?

Tags: android

My app has a [floating search view](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview) that takes full width of screen. It will go behind navigation bar when orientation is landscape, so I want to add some margins to it. The problem is that when I rotate left-landscape(navi bar on the right), the right portion of my floating view is behind navi bar, and when I rotate right-landscape, left portion is covered, so I need a proper way to know which side to add more margins.

I currently have

```
switch (getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        break;
}
```

which I tested that `Surface.ROTATION_90` would be when the device is left-rotated (navi bar on the right), but I don't know if this is the case for all devices. I can't seem to find any doc that defines the difference between `Surface.ROTATION_90` and `Surface.ROTATION_270`. If there's a better way to have system automatically adjust the [floating search bar](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview) is even better. Setting `android:fitsSystemWindows` to true does not help.

Comment: Try getResources().getConfiguration().orientation instead of getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()

Comment: @user1865027 Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Thracian I looked all over for how to get the current orientation in a jetpack compose app, but outside of a UI (i.e. helper class used in a service) and your reply here is the only one that actually worked out well; so I wanted to say thank you (as indirectly as it helped me - my inquiry was figuring out if the rotation values indicated landscape/portrait - having given up trying to query the orientation).  `context.resources.configuration.orientation` would be how to go about it using property acces stemming from a `LocalContext.current` (i.e. `context`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation()):

That should work the same in all devices, that is, *"If the device is rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise, to compensate rendering will be rotated by 90 degrees clockwise and thus the returned value here will be Surface.ROTATION_90."*

Naturally, ROTATION_270 is the opposite direction (right). ROTATION_90/270 won't necessarily mean Landscape mode, though, so if you also want to know that you should also check for current orientation.