# how to know if device is left or right landscape?

Tags: android

I want to do something different depending on the in which the screen is rotated for this there are four options landscape right, landscape left, portrait right, and portrait left, I know how to detect landscape and portrait but don't know how to detect between their right and left counterparts. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692806/how-to-know-if-device-is-left-landscape-or-right-landscape) but everything is now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You should use the onOrientationChanged event listener found in the OrientationEventListener class(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener)
It returns an integer ranging from 0 to 359 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

`defaultDisplay` was marked as deprecated in API level 30 and above. So for build version greater than 30 we have to use new solution.

Below is the code i used.

```
val rotation = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    display?.rotation
} else {
    windowManager.defaultDisplay.rotation
}

val angle = when (rotation) {
    Surface.ROTATION_90 -> 90
    Surface.ROTATION_180 -> 180
    Surface.ROTATION_270 -> 270
    else -> 0
}
```